# Using append to get data from a nested list

Tags: python, html, json, append

Currently my code is like this:

```
.append("Last Name {}, First Name {} Stats: {}".format(result["L_Name"], result["F_Name"], result["Stats"]))
```

this code works but the output isn't exactly the ones I want the code to display.

the problem is that the **Stats** has another list

- L_Name: Doe
- F_Name: John
- Contribution:

  - Month
  - Value
  - Returns

is there a way to just pick out only the **Value** from the **Stats** by just adding or changing something in my append? 
specifically in this part?

```
, result["Stats"]))
```

Comment: Can you post the list and dictionary, or a sample.

Comment: as I have seen you are trying to get format in string if so then you can try appending `str(result["Stats"])` instead of `result["Stats"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only after one value of Stats, you can get the value at a certain index. Assuming Value is at index 1 and Stats is a standard Python list:

```
, result["Stats"][1]))
```

Comment: you need to iterate or map all elements in append section

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you can access the items of the JSON structure in the format string itself. This is clearer than using positional arguments if the format string is very complicated. Additionally, you can pass the whole dictionary into `format_map`:

```
l.append("Last Name {L_Name}, First Name {F_Name} Stats: {Stats[Value]}"
         .format_map(result))
```

(In Python 2, `format_map` doesn't exist, use `format(**result)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the future please consider posting working code only so we can reproduce your issue. I am going to assume `result['stats']` is a dictionary and the bulleted list are key:value pairs.

You can access the `"Contribution"` key of your `result["Stats"]` dictionary which results in list. You can then slice the second element of the list with `[1]`.

```
_.append("Last Name {}, First Name {} Stats: {}".format(
         result["L_Name"], 
         result["F_Name"],
         result["Stats"]["Contribution"][1]))
```

This assumes `result['stats']` looks like:

```
result['stats'] = {
    'L_Name': 'Doe',
    'F_Name': 'John',
    'Contribution': [Month, Value, Returns]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone I was able to get a hint from your answers

```
result["Stats"]["Contribution"][1]
```

worked well for me